# Disabling/changing style of a button through Node.js/API?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I've tried searching this up with little information and and I suppose it's more of a general question to expand my knowledge.

For my MERN app, there's a list of posts and each post has a score, an upvote button, and a downvote button. I'd like to disable/change the styling of the upvote/downvote button after a user votes for that specific post but let them still vote on the other unvoted posts. I'm storing the user_id in my documents in MongoDB and I've created GET route to retrieve who and if a user has voted. My question is how would I go about disabling the upvote button for a specific post that a user has voted on?

I've come across a few items (res.send, res.render) but I'm not sure if there's a proper way I should be going about this.

Any insight would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, what you can do is have a variable in the API in boolean. For example for the upvote if it is true, then the voter has voted and if false the voter has not voted.
On the front end if you're using React, create a boolean state and initialize it to false eg hasVoted:false

Whenever you run your GET, check whether the variable from API is true, and if so, run a setState and change the front end state to true.
 You can then alter your button functionality in render if this.state.hasVoted is true or false accordingly.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply :) I had a question about that implementation - wouldn't that disable all the other upvote/downvote buttons for other posts?

Maybe I'm missing something but your feedback is appreciated!

Comment: It would not disable the rest since when you render, you're rendering individual upvote or downvote. The hasVoted is just a state that will be checked by the render before it actually renders the component you want. Have I answered clearly? If not let me know

Comment: Hi there! I thought I had it figured out but I'm running into issues still unfortunately. I have my GET which returns all the posts that a user has upvoted as an array, should each item in the array have a boolean that says the item has been voted on?

Comment: That is how I would do it. Every individual post should have it.